# Using method reference to remove elements from a List

Tags: java, java-8

What's wrong with my code?

I want to remove all the elements starting with **A** from the `List` `list`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Predicate<String> TTT = "A"::startsWith;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("Magician");
    list.add("Assistant");
    System.out.println(list); // [Magician, Assistant]

    list.removeIf(TTT);
    System.out.println(list); // expected output: [Magician]

}
```

However, `removeIf` doesn't remove anything from the list.

Comment: is TTT a correct ***Predicate<String>*** ????

Comment: Yes, what is wrong with this code, does it not compile? does ist not do what you expect? what excactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"A"::startsWith` is a method reference that can be assigned to a `Predicate<String>`, and when that `Predicate<String>` is tested against some other `String`, it would check whether the String `"A"` starts with that other `String`, not the other way around.

`list.removeIf(TTT)` won't remove anything from `list`, since "A" doesn't start with neither "Magician" nor "Assistant".

---

You can use a lambda expression instead:

```
Predicate<String> TTT = s -> s.startsWith("A");
```

The only way your original `"A"::startsWith` predicate would remove anything from the list is if the list would contain the `String` `"A"` or an empty `String`.

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra Well, you can't. At least not with the `"A"::startsWith` method reference. You can create a static method that checks if a String starts with "A" - `public static startsWithA (String s) {return s.startsWith("A");}` - and use that method's reference `YourClass::startsWithA`. I don't think it would make much sense though.

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra You could also do: `BiFunction<String, String, Boolean> fun = String::startsWith;
     list.removeIf(i -> fun.apply(i, "A"));`, if you really _must_ use a method reference.

Comment: @Eran what is difference between **String::startWith** and   **""::startWith** then ?

Comment: `""::startWith` is a method reference attached to a specific String instance - `""` (similar to your `"A"::startsWith`), so `"".startWith(someString)` will be executed if you assign it to a `Predicate<String>` and call the `test` method. `String::startWith` is a method reference without a specific String instance, which means that it requires 2 String instances in order to be used - the instance on which `startsWith` will be called and the String passed as argument to that method. @HasnainAliBohra

Comment: @Eran if i declared my reference as **"A".startWith** then how can i pass first argument as another string

Answer (score 0):

```
BiPredicate<String, String> b1 = String::startsWith;
BiPredicate<String, String> b2 = (string, prefix) -> string.startsWith(prefix);
System.out.println(b1.test("chicken", "chick"));
System.out.println(b2.test("chicken", "chick"));
```

The method reference combines two techniques. `**startsWith()**`
is an instance method. This means that the **first parameter in the lambda is used
as the instance on which to call the method**. The **second parameter is passed to the
startsWith() method itself**. This is example of how method references save a
good bit of typing.